# POSIX sh: Best solution to create a unique temporary directory

Tags: sh, posix

Currently, the only POSIX compliant way of creating a unique directory (that I know) is by creating a unique file using the [`mkstemp()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkstemp.html) function exposed by [`m4`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/m4.html) and then replacing this file with a directory:

```bash
tmpdir="$(printf "mkstemp(tmp.)" | m4)"
unlink "$tmpdir"
mkdir "$tmpdir"
```

This seems rather hacky though, and I also don't know how safe/secure it is.
Is there better/more direct POSIX compliant way to create a unique temporary directory in shellscript, or is this as good as it gets?

The `mktemp` command is out of the question because it is not defined in POSIX.

Comment: Assuming things like `uuidgen` aren't allowed, you could repeatedly create a psuedo-random string of characters and check to see if a directory with that name already exists. Things like `date +%N` and the process id may help, but I don't know how you could guarantee universal uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect using unlink/mkdir to be statistically safe as the window of opportunity for another process to create the directory is likely to be small. But a simple fix is just to retry on failure:

```
while
    tmpdir="$(printf "mkstemp(tmp.)" | m4)"
    unlink "$tmpdir"
    ! mkdir "$tmpdir"
do : ; done
```

Similarly, we could simply attempt to create a directory directly without creating a file first. Directory creation is atomic so there is no race condition. We do have to pick a name that doesn't exist but, as above, if we fail we can just try again.

For example, using a simple random number generator:

**mkdtemp.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

# initial entropy, the more we can get the better 
random=$(( $(date +%s) + $$ ))

while
    # C standard rand(), without truncation
    # cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator
    random=$(( (1103515245*random + 12345) % 2147483648 ))

    # optionally, shorten name a bit
    tmpdir=$( printf "tmp.%x" $random )

    # loop until new directory is created
    ! mkdir $tmpdir 2>&-
do : ; done

printf %s "$tmpdir"
```

Notes:

- `%s` (seconds since epoch) is not a POSIX-standard format option to [date](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html); you could use something like `%S%M%H%j` instead
- POSIX says "[Only signed long integer arithmetic is required](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html)" which I believe means at least 2^31

Comment: The largest signed long (4-byte) integer is 2147483647 (2^31 - 1). So... not sure if this is POSIX compliant.

Comment: @ErikE you can negate the modulus to -2147483648 if you want to be safe

Comment: That is fascinating...